# Why can't my method refer to the constructor props of the class it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a JavaScript class like so:

```
export class btnNumbers {

    constructor(index){
        this.index=index;
        this.btn = document.createElement(`div`);
        
        this.btn.classList.add('btn__normalState');
        this.btn.innerText = index;
        this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.showIndex )
        
        const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer');
        btnContainer.appendChild(this.btn);
    }

    showIndex(){
        console.log(this.index)
    }
```

and I am using this class in another js file like so:

```
for ( let i=1; i<=500 ;i++){
    var btn = new btnNumbers(i);}
```

so this creates 500 of theses elements that are clickable, and they should return the index, but it does not, it returns undefined instead.

I can't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` value of the event handler function or use an arrow function; otherwise, the `this` value will be set to the HTML element on which the event listener is attached.

```
this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.showIndex.bind(this));
// or
this.btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>this.showIndex());
```

```js
class btnNumbers {
  constructor(index) {
    this.index = index;
    this.btn = document.createElement(`div`);
    this.btn.classList.add('btn__normalState');
    this.btn.innerText = index;
    this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.showIndex.bind(this))
    const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer');
    btnContainer.appendChild(this.btn);
  }

  showIndex() {
    console.log(this.index)
  }
}
for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
  var btn = new btnNumbers(i);
}
```

```html
<div id="btnContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: oh yes !! i forgot about this !! thanks so much it solves the issue perfect !

Comment: @julBayonna Glad to help.

Comment: sure i just need to wait 5 minutes apparently, can't do it right away, but i will for sure !

Comment: very sorry guys, i will do better searching next time. apologies